# JaxB How to marshall the content of a list as individual tags

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I'm using JAXB as marshaller.

I have an object that contains a List of Strings and other properties. I would like to marshall the list contents as individual tag.

I have in code `List<String> items`. If I add to the list the strings "apple","banana","orange"  I would like when marshalling that the resulting xml is:

```
<items>
   <apple/>
   <banana/>
   <orange/>
</items>
```

Is this feasable?? Or, to obtain that result, how have I to change the object?

(Sorry for formatting, I cannot do better)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### My Advice

My advice is don't do it this way.  Instead have your XML message be the following (it will make it easier for everyone to process your XML):

```
<items>
   <item>apple</item>
   <item>banana</item>
   <item>orange</item>
</items>
```

---

### How You Could Do It

OK, you have decided not to follow my advice :).  Here is how you can do it:

1. Create an `XmlAdapter` that can convert a `String` to an instance of `org.w3c.dom.Element` with its name equal to the `String`.

   ```
   import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;
   import javax.xml.parsers.*;
   import org.w3c.dom.*;

   public class StringAdapter extends XmlAdapter<Object, String> {

       private Document document;

       @Override
       public String unmarshal(Object v) throws Exception {
       Element element = (Element) v;
       return element.getTagName();
       }

       @Override
       public Object marshal(String v) throws Exception {
       return getDocument().createElement(v);
       }

       private Document getDocument() throws Exception {
       if(null == document) {
           DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
           DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
           document = db.newDocument();
       }
       return document;
       }

   }
   ```
2. Annotate your `List<String>` field/property with `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` pointing to your `XmlAdapter` and the `@XmlAnyElement` annotation.

   ```
    import java.util.*;
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;

    @XmlRootElement
    public class Items {

       private List<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();

       @XmlAnyElement
       @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(StringAdapter.class)
       public List<String> getItems() {
       return items;
       }

     }
   ```
3. To improve performance, make sure your `XmlAdapter` holds an instance of `Document` and set the `XMLAdapter` on the `Marshaller` to make it stateful to avoid the need to recreate it each time the `XmlAdapter` is called.

   ```
   import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
   import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;

   public class Demo {

       public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
       JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Items.class);

       Items items = new Items();
       items.getItems().add("apple");
       items.getItems().add("banana");
       items.getItems().add("orange");

       Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
       marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
       marshaller.setAdapter(new StringAdapter());
       marshaller.marshal(items, System.out);
       }

   }
   ```

Comment: Great!! Thanks! Unfortunately the XML in that way is for me a requirement not a choice (has been a choice for someone else!)...

Comment: For completeness to other readers, to completely obtain the expected result, it's also needed to annotate the list as @XmlElementWrapper(name="empty")